# JavaFX Disable arrow keys for TabPane but not children inside tabs

Tags: javafx, listener

I have several [JFXTabPanes](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) accross the application and they have mutliple tabs ...

They have inside `StackPanes` with multiple nodes each one . What i want is to disable the arrow key events for the `JFXTabPanes` and only allow them for the children inside the tabs .

I want to do that because sometimes when the user is pressing arrow keys inside the   stackpanes children , then another tab is selected on the JFXTabPane which is annoying .

What i am doing so far.

```
tabPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> {
    if (event.getCode().isArrowKey()) {                  
        System.out.println("Is arrow key");              
        event.consume();                                 
    }                                                    
});
```

And the children have their own key event listeners by they don't work anymore after i add the event filter on the tabPane :(

```
// -- KeyListeners                         
someChildrenInsideTabPane.setOnKeyReleased(key -> {                  
    System.out.println("Key RELEASED");    
    if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)    
        nextSpectrumAnalyzer();            
    else if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
        previousSpectrumAnalyzer();        
});
```

Comment: What happens if you consume the event in your `onKeyReleased` handler? That should stop the event from bubbling up to the tab pane and hopefully keep users from switching tabs.

Comment: @Slaw Good idea ... but should i consume it for each and every child : ) ?

Comment: If by "every child" you mean every node within a single tab, I'd say no. You should be able to add a handler to the root node of the tab's content and consume the event there.

Comment: @Slaw Great i will try :)